# What's the difference between tempfile and mktemp?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Most systems I've encountered have both `tempfile(1)` and `mktemp(1)`. There are syntactic differences, and `mktemp` can also create directories, but they otherwise seem to do the same thing.

Is there any difference between the two? Why do both exist? Is one more standard than the other? If I just want to create a temporary file safely, is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

I suspect there's some interesting Unix lore behind this, but my searches turn up nothing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> I suspect there's some interesting Unix lore behind this ...

The [history](http://www.mktemp.org/manual.html#6) of `mktemp` can be traced to [OpenBSD 2.1](http://openbsd.org/21.html).  However, it became a part of GNU coreutils much later.  [This](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-10/msg00051.html) post announced the inclusion of `mktemp` for `coreutils`.

Until then, `tempfile` was being used by a number of programs.  There was also a [proposal](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-10/msg00133.html) to make `tempfile` a wrapper around `mktemp`, which was [rejected](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-10/msg00134.html) to discourage use of `tempfile`.

However, the following was added to `tempfile` manual:

> Exclusive  creation is not guaranteed when creating files on NFS partitions.  `tempfile` cannot make temporary directories.  `tempfile` is deprecated; you should use `mktemp(1)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I just overlooked that bit of the manpage :)

Answer (score 5):

It says in tempfile's manual that:

`tempfile - create a temporary file in a safe manner`

While in mktemp:

`mktemp - create a temporary file or directory`

They're probably just almost the same, only that the implementation is a little different.

As said in the manual, `tempfile` actually has some precautions like:

> a) In case the environment variable `TMPDIR` exists and contains the
>   name of an appropriate directory, that is used.
>
> b) Otherwise, if the `--directory` argument is specified and
>   appropriate, it is used.
>
> c) Otherwise, `P_tmpdir` (as defined in `<stdio.h>`) is used when
>   appropriate.
>
> d) Finally an implementation-defined directory (`/tmp`) may be used.

It's actually useful if the script trusts `mktemp` or `tempfile` enough that it's certain that a temporary file or directory would be created. But I don't see much problem just using `mktemp` if you run precautions in your script yourself. You can use `[ -e ]`, `[ -f ]`, `[ -d ]`, `[ -L ]`, etc. to verify if a file could actually be made/was already made. Even check if something's writable, readable, and/or executable with -r, -w and -x. In bash, see `help test`.

Still for the sake of continuous runtime perhaps you would better rely on `tempfile` when running your code in multiple environments. Just make sure that it's available everywhere enough. With `which` or with `type -P` you could check which one of them is available. An example:

```
create_temp() {
    if type -P tempfile >/dev/null; then
        # use tempfile based from $1
    elif type -P mktemp > /dev/null; then
        # use mktemp based from $1
    else
        echo "Can't find temporary file creator."
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: The linux tempfile(1) manual notes tempfile is deprecated; you should use mktemp(1) instead."

Answer (score 1):

From the source code sight of things (on debian) `tempfile` is from the package `debianutils`  and uses the libc function `tempnam()` while `mktemp` is from GNU coreutils and doesn't use the libc function