# What is the alpine linux equivalent to ubuntu tempfile?

Tags: temporary-files, alpine-linux

What's the alpine linux equivalent to ubuntu's [tempfile](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tempfile.1.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `tempfile` is deprecated in favor of `mktemp`, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717518/4126114) SO answer